# How can i achieve the percentage splitting accordingly in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to achieve this with **ANGULAR** i want to split the percentage as shown in image if the txtBox1 has 75% i want remining txt2,txt3 split the reming 25% and if i change the txt1 to 50% i want other to be 25% and 25% like dynamically splitting the values might vary

This is what i tried I know its not much [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3au3cg?file=src/main.ts) i am new to angular

[image: Please refer the image]

[image]

[image]

***Is it possible to achieve this ? please help me out***

Comment: Can you please include your code so that we can work with it, ideally in a StackBlitz. It is definitely achievable though

Comment: Hello @nate-kumar please do check the stackblitz i have not written much as i am super new to angular

Comment: Try this first with simple HTML and CSS. Then, find out that you should use a toolkit like Bootstrap. Also, find out that you probably need a portable layout, that should work on large and small screens, and that percentage splitting is perhaps not what you really want

Comment: @Roland actually i am looking for the percentage splitting logic only i am not focused on UI i shared those images so it would be easy to convey

Comment: Your question has up and down votes for "does this Q show research effort?". So, have you tried without angular, with plain html and css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that always updates the other two controls when a given control is edited and then blurred. There are optimisations and validation checks that could/should be implemented to improve the solution, but hopefully this is sufficient to demonstrate the concept

```
interface TextForm {
  textbox1: FormControl<string>;
  textbox2: FormControl<string>;
  textbox3: FormControl<string>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div>
        <input type="text" formControlName="textbox1" (blur)="calculateRemainders('textbox1')" />
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" formControlName="textbox2" (blur)="calculateRemainders('textbox2')" />
        <hr />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" formControlName="textbox3" (blur)="calculateRemainders('textbox3')" />
        <hr />
      </div>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  form: FormGroup<TextForm>;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      textbox1: [''],
      textbox2: [''],
      textbox3: [''],
    });
    this.applyInitValues();
  }

  applyInitValues() {
    let count = +Object.keys(this.form.controls).length;
    let equality = (100 / count).toFixed(1);

    this.form.setValue({
      textbox1: equality,
      textbox2: equality,
      textbox3: equality,
    });
  }

  calculateRemainders(editedControlKey: keyof TextForm) {
    // Get array of controls as [[controlKey1, control1], [controlKey2, control2], [controlKey3, control3]]
    // Sort to make sure that the first index is the control that was edited
    const controls: [string, FormControl<string>][] = Object.entries(this.form.controls).sort(([controlKey]) => controlKey === editedControlKey ? 1 : 0);

    // Ensure the first control value is set to 1 decimal place and calculate the remaining 2 values (also to 1.d.p)
    const editedControlValue: number = this.toOneDecimalPlace(Number(this.form.get(editedControlKey).value));
    const firstRemainder: number = this.toOneDecimalPlace((100 - editedControlValue) / 2);
    const secondRemainder: number = this.toOneDecimalPlace(100 - editedControlValue - firstRemainder);

    // Apply the updated values to each control (as strings)
    controls[0][1].setValue(`${editedControlValue}`);
    controls[1][1].setValue(`${firstRemainder}`);
    controls[2][1].setValue(`${secondRemainder}`);
  }

  toOneDecimalPlace(number: number) {
    return Math.round(number * 10) / 10
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9rytqv?file=src/main.ts)

Comment: thanks for the answer i have already given green tick.is it possible to do like when i have 50 in textbox1 and it will give 25,25 and if I change the middle 25 to 35 and the last textbox should change to 15 and first,second remain same, I am just asking

Comment: It's definitely possible, but you have to define your behaviour as there are a few ways this could be done. What happens if you change textbox1 to 50, then textbox2 to 35, then textbox1 to 40? Should textbox2 and textbox3 redistribute again like in the first instance? Should textbox2 never change (because the user has entered a value already, i.e 35) in which case maybe only textbox3 would recalculate. What would then happen if the user had entered a value in all 3 textboxes, would all future input be ignored (as all 3 have user-entered values) etc :)

Answer (score 0):

The logic could be as follows:

```
  const restPercentages = 100 - this.form.controls.textbox1.value;
  this.form.controls.textbox2.setValue(restPercentages/2);
  this.form.controls.textbox3.setValue(restPercentages/2);
```

I don't know the moment you would like to make such check. Maybe on blur event of textbox1? and disabling both textbox2, textbox3 are the way to go.